# spf13-vim disable tab highlighting

Tags: vim

I'm an absolut vim-newbie so I thought I'll try it with some preconfigured distribution like [spf13-vim](http://vim.spf13.com/). So to my question, I would like to disable the "tab-highlighting" because I find it kind of distracting...
I think this picture should make clear what I mean
[image: VIM]

Comment: Vim "distributions" like _spf-13_ and _Janus_ lure you with a quick install and out-of-the-box settings, but you pay the price with increased complexity (you need to understand both Vim's runtime loading scheme and the arbitrary conventions of the distribution) and inflexibility (the distribution may make some things easier, but other things very difficult). Vim is incredibly customizable, using someone else's customization makes no sense.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Even I was lured but after hours of just editor debugging, I started with vanilla vim, and I got better startup times as well as something comfortable and intuitive. Vim beginners should play with the plain vim for maybe a year then use these preconfig setups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can toggle them on/off with `,ig`.

Answer (score 5):

Put a line below in your ~/.vimrc.local or ~/.vimrc.before.local to disable indent guide by default. You can `<leader>ig` as well.

```
let g:indent_guides_enable_on_vim_startup = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

write `set nolist` in your .vimrc.local to turn it off.

see `:h list`

```
'list'          boolean (default off)

List mode: Show tabs as CTRL-I is displayed, display $ after end of
line.  Useful to see the difference between tabs and spaces and for
trailing blanks.  Further changed by the 'listchars' option.
```