# Remove tab dots from vim indentation/tabs

Tags: vim, spf13vim

I am using [spf13-vim](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim) and whenever I press tab, I get these dots. They are there even when I press space.

[image]

How I can remove these dots. I want the indentation to happen but without dots. I searched a lot on the web but there is no information available or I could not find.

What changes should I do in my `.vimrc` to hide these dots?

**EDIT**

I tried `,ig` command or added `let g:indent_guides_enable_on_vim_startup = 0` in `.vimrc.local` but I am still getting the dots.

**EDIT**

`:set nolist` worked for me, as suggested by @Christian Brabandt in the comments

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904249/spf13-vim-disable-tab-highlighting, although it may be useful to leave this question be to help people who don't know they want to disable `tab highlighting`

Comment: I went through that question while searching, but it did not help, maybe i used it wrong. I typed it as 'esc' to enter command mode and then `,ig`. Was I correct?

Comment: Much depends on the specific distribution (spf13-vim) and what exactly they've done . I will take a look at spf13-vim when I get some time

Comment: I my opinion it is best to avoid or at least be wary of Vim distributions as the authors opinions often differ from your own. [The best general advice I have found after learning vimtutor](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4119/778).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do goes by the term disabling tab highlighting. More information is here:

[spf13-vim disable tab highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904249/spf13-vim-disable-tab-highlighting)

Answer (score 0):

Add `set nolist` to `~/.vimrc.local` to override default `spf13-vim` settings.

That behaviour is caused by the following lines in `.vimrc` (233, 234):

```
set list
set listchars=tab:›\ ,trail:•,extends:#,nbsp:. " Highlight problematic whitespace
```

`list` mode is used to display whitespace and special characters, `listchars` allows to configure corresponding characters that will be displayed.